# Multi-stage Probability

Tags: probability, permutations

I think the easiest way to explain what I'm having trouble with is to give an example question:

A monkey is given 12 blocks: 3 Squares, 3 Rectangles, 3 Triangles, 3 Circles. Calculate the probability of it drawing three of each kind in order - say, 3 triangles, then 3 squares and so on.

I have done this question and gotten the right answer, however, I am not happy with my working out:

$\frac{2}{11}* \frac{1}{10}* \frac{1}{4}* \frac{1}{7}* \frac{2}{5}* \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{15400}$

As you can see, I've basically gone through step by step, calculating the probability of each individual draw.

My textbook shows the answer as this:

$\frac{(4!)(3!)^4}{12!}=\frac{1}{15400}$

I have been told the reasoning is that firstly, there are $P_4^4$ ways of drawing the pattern in general (i.e. TCSR, CTRS, RTSC, etc.)... I understand this step but not sure as to why it is being done.

Secondly, each pattern can be arranged in $P_3^3$ ways (i.e. T1, T3, T2). I understand this but i have no idea as to why the order of drawing these is relevant.

Then from there I have absolutely no idea where any of the other part of the calculation arises from.

Could someone please walk me through this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can be confusing! Order is relevant here because probability = (# desired)/(total). The things we are counting here are *orders you can choose shapes in*. There are $12!$ different orders to choose $12$ shapes in, so that's the total.

Now the problem is counting how many different orders have runs of three of each kind. For example, here are some of them:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&T_1T_3T_2C_1C_2C_3S_3S_1S_2R_1R_2R_3\\
&T_3T_1T_2S_3S_1S_2C_1C_2C_3R_1R_2R_3\\
&C_1C_2C_3R_1R_2R_3S_1S_2S_3T_1T_2T_3\\
\end{aligned}
$$

There are five independent choices: how you order the $4$ blocks (TCSR or CRST) and how you order the $3$ objects within each block ($C_1C_2C_3$ or $C_2C_3C_1$). So we multiply them together and get:

$$4!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot3!$$

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thanks! But one small thing I still don't understand is why order matters with T1T2T3, for example. They're all the exact same shape, so why is the order they're picked up in relevant?

Comment: Good question. It's because what we've decided to count is orders to pick up objects in. For example, suppose there were only triangles in the bag, and we were calculating the probability of drawing three triangles in a row. The probability should be $1$. We could count orders, and calculate it as (# orders with all triangles)/(# total orders) = $3!$/$3!$ = 1. Or we could count something else, like unordered sets the monkey could end up with. There's only one of those (all three triangles) and it has the property we want, so we calculate $1/1 = 1$. (cont.)

Comment: ... So, probability works regardless of what you count, but you must count the appropriate thing for the problem. Here the question involves order (runs of the same kind) so we must count order the whole way through. We were bound to do that ever since we put $12!$ on the bottom, since that number treats everything as a distinct object. (So if we didn't treat the objects as distinct when calculating the numerator, we'd be undercounting).

Comment: Ahhh okay! So it's because we've assumed that every shape is different by saying that there are 12! different ways we can draw the shapes? Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRhapsody: Exactly, you got it.